# How to pass direction to the query function when implementing bi-directional infinite list with React Query?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-query, tanstack

I'm implementing a bi-directional infinite list using `useInfiniteQuery` from React Query, based on the [docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/infinite-queries#what-if-i-want-to-implement-a-bi-directional-infinite-list). The only parameter that gets passed to the `queryFn` is an object containing the page parameter (one of the two cursors).

It's not quite clear to me, in this case, how I can make my backend aware of the direction of the query (i.e. whether I want to get the records after or before the given cursor value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the assumption that the backend can deliver two cursors, one for forward pagination and one for backward, and that `getNextPageParam` and `getPreviousPageParam` will then be able to calculate one pageParam correctly.

However, if your backend requires to different params, like `before=...` or `after=...`, then you'd need access to the fetch direction. We've added this in v5, because we've made substantial improvements to infinite queries there (currently in alpha): https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/guides/query-functions#queryfunctioncontext

Comment: Is there a way to implement this "direction" thing in v3?

Comment: Maybe do it through "pageParam"?